# Kearning between two glyphs skia

Tags: android, c++, skia

I'm new in skia.

I want to know, how to get the kerning(or advance) between two glyphs?

In my project i inluded modul of skia, and in the native have

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_KernMe_NativeSkia_getHelloFromNative(JNIEnv *env,
        jclass clazz, jobject assetManager, jstring path, jstring text) {

AAssetManager *mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
    if (mgr == NULL) 
       return false;
    const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(path, 0); 


AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, nativeString, AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
if (NULL == asset)
    return false;

SkStream* stream = new AssetStream(asset, true);
SkTypeface* face = SkTypeface::CreateFromStream(stream);
if(face == NULL)
    return false;
```

In jstring I have two symbols("ab"), I want to create to gplyphs and get information about this glyphs(etc. advance, kearning). I'm seeking function like this:

```
int Get_Kerning(leftGlyph, rightGlyph)
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: **Please** add more information. Tell us *clearly* what you're aiming for and what you have actually *tried*. Some code would also be appreciated. If you can't provide any of the above, then consider reading skia's *manual pages*.

Comment: I'm sorry for so little information, if need be I will write more in detail